# Form Authentication Security

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

Below is an example of my code:

This is a page I would like to lock down to users only.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Profile()
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    var users = _service.Get().Where(x => x.EmailAddress.ToLower() == ticket.Name);
    var user = users.First();
    return View(user);
}
```

This is how I log my user's in:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    var exs = _service.ValidateUser(model.EmailAddress, model.Password);
    if (exs.Any())
    {
        AddModelExceptionsToModelState(ModelState, exs);
        return View(model); 
    }

    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.EmailAddress,model.RemeberMe);
    return RedirectToAction("Profile");
}
```

I'm not sure of the security of what I am doing, It's not important information been stored but I would like it to be safe.

Does the above login/authorize method come across as been secure/safe to use?

If so how can I create a method to return the logged in user? Am i best to do this in an abstract controller class and then inter hit from it?

Is there better way's of handling user's logging in and out?

I am using Entity Framework and MVC5. Note i cannot user the membership database as it's not allowed within this project.

Comment: Use the new type of membership that ships within mvc5. Don't use the concrete types, but implement the interfaces yourself instead. It's open sourced so you can get a clue on how they perform the standard membership actions.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Really belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

OWIN Authentication is a new implementation of Authentication within asp.net mvc5

There is an excellent blog post by Scott Allen that describes the concept and the Interfaces / Classes used by this system.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/11/25/asp-net-core-identity.aspx

If you have a pluralsight account check this course too

http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is fine. You can however, simplify the controller that uses the cookie:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Profile()
{
  string userName = this.User.Identity.Name;
  var users = _service.Get().Where(x => x.EmailAddress.ToLower() == userName );
  var user = users.First();
  return View(user);
}
```

This is because the forms authentication module does almost the same job you did in the first two lines of your original approach but the module sets the principal for the request lifetime and you can access the principal the way I show above.